# Efficiently preserving array dimensions in R

Tags: r, arrays

The below R code fills an array of specified dimensions with positive integers generated randomly via a probability vector.

```
subset.haps <- NULL
haps <- 1:4
num.specs <- 100
probs <- rep(1/4, 4)
perms <- 10000
K <- 1   

gen.perms <- function() {
  if (is.null(subset.haps)) {
    sample(haps, size = num.specs, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
  } else {
    resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]
    resample(subset.haps, size = num.specs, replace = TRUE, prob = probs[subset.haps])
  }
}

pop <- array(dim = c(perms, num.specs, K))

for (i in 1:K) {
  pop[, , i] <- replicate(perms, gen.perms()) 
}
```

However, profiling the above code suggests that improvements can be made.

The 'for' loop can be eliminated using rep()

```
rep(replicate(perms, gen.perms()), K)
```

However, this method does not produce an array, nor preserves array dimensions.

Of course, wrapping the above modified code within as.array() will fix the second issue, but the output does not resemble a typical array in structure.

**My question**

How can I ensure the array structure (i.e., dimensions) is preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just make `pop` then set its `dim` attribute afterwards:

```
pop <- rep(replicate(perms, gen.perms()), K)
dim(pop) <-  c(perms, num.specs, K)
```

And to prove it:

```r
class(pop)
# [1] "array"
dim(pop)
# [1] 10000   100     1
pop[2020,23,1]
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks, though I don’t see what the line in the proof adds to the solution

Comment: @compbiostats I was simply demonstrating that the resulting object behaves as expected, including having the ability to be accessed by triple index. Funny things can sometimes happen when you change the attributes of data structures (or the attributes can change unbidden, as you have demonstrated). Anyway, if you think the answer has solved your problem, please consider accepting it to allow others who have similar difficulties to find their way to the solution.